# Passing Data between view controllers using combine framework

Tags: swift

I am new to combine and was trying to play around in combine framework. But I am facing some issues when i try to pass a string from my tableview to detail page using a `PassThroughSubject` Below is my code.

The problem I face is sometimes I do not get a title in detail view controller but when you go back to tableview and click on the same row again it works. And same happens often

{

```
// MARK: Variables -

var viewModel = GitHubListingViewModel()
private var cancellables = Set<AnyCancellable>()
let reuseIdentifier = "Cell"

// MARK: Outlets -

@IBOutlet weak var gitHubListingTable: UITableView!

// MARK: Life Cycle -
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    
    self.title = " Trending List"
    
    gitHubListingTable.dataSource = self
    gitHubListingTable.delegate = self
    
    self.gitHubListingTable.register(UINib(nibName: "GitHubListCell", bundle: nil), forCellReuseIdentifier: reuseIdentifier)
  
    viewModel.getGitHubListing()
  
    viewModel.$trendingGitHubList
        .receive(on: RunLoop.main)
        .sink { [weak self] _ in
            self?.gitHubListingTable.reloadData()
        }
        .store(in: &cancellables)
    
}
```

}

```
extension GitHubListing: UITableViewDataSource, UITableViewDelegate {
    
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        return viewModel.getListCount()
    }
    
    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        
        let cell = gitHubListingTable.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: reuseIdentifier, for: indexPath) as! GitHubListCell
        
        viewModel.trendingGitHubListing
            .receive(on: RunLoop.main)
            .sink { gitHubModel in
              //  if let gitHubModel = gitHubModel {
                    cell.configureCell(with: gitHubModel[indexPath.row])
              //  }
            }
            .store(in: &cancellables)
        
        return cell
    }
    
    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
        let gitHubDetails = GitHubLinkDetails()
        tableView.deselectRow(at: indexPath, animated: true)
       
        viewModel.trendingGitHubListing
            .receive(on: RunLoop.main)
            .sink { githublist in
              //  if let githublist = githublist {
                    gitHubDetails.githubDetails.send(githublist[indexPath.row])
                gitHubDetails.sample.send("Title")
            //    }
            }
            .store(in: &cancellables)
        navigationController?.pushViewController(gitHubDetails, animated: true)
    }
    
    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, heightForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> CGFloat {
        100
    }
    
}
```

My detail view controller -

```
import UIKit
import Combine
import SDWebImage
class GitHubLinkDetails: UIViewController {
    
    // MARK: Variables -
    var sample = PassthroughSubject<String, Never>()

override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
       self.getDetails()
        
        sample
            .sink { title in
                self.title = title
            }
            .store(in: &cancellables)
     
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

PassthroughSubject based on apple documentation drops value if there are no subscribers(https://developer.apple.com/documentation/combine/passthroughsubject). To solve this issue with your current structure use CurrentValueSubject instead of PassthroughSubject. By using CurrentValueSubject you can always access the last published value even if you subscribe to the subject after publishing value.

Comment: `var githubDetails1 : CurrentValueSubject<GitHubModel,Never>?`

Comment: I added this code and used the same way to get data  `githubDetails1?
            .sink{[weak self ] github in
             
                self?.deployData(githubdata: github)
            }
            .store(in: &cancellables)`

I  am not able to reflect any data at all. Please point out if anything i am missing

Comment: @Sabaz What you've posted in your comment wouldn't work because you never initialise the publisher. Why not just use `@Published` property wrapper as it's only going to be used once to setup the data right. Something like this would make a lot more sense: `@Published var githubDetailsOne: GitHubModel?` Then before you `sink` the result you can do `.compactMap { $0 }`

Comment: For me PassthroughSubject didn't work but CurrentValueSubject works. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

In your `didSelectCellAt` method, you set up your Detail View Controller in the `.sink` closure (which makes sense, since that's when you get the data). However, you then push the ViewController outside the closure. As a result, you have no guarantee that the setup is completed when the VC is pushed.

See what happens when you include `navigationController?.pushViewController(...)` as part of the `.sink` closure. Does that work as expected?

Comment: I get the same problem